# phonegap :: navigator.notification.activityStart() and loadingStart() not working

Tags: cordova

I try to call loadingStart() and activityStart() on phonegap1.0 (inside onDeviceReady) but it is not working. is there a known reason? should it work well?

thnx!

Comment: Just curious, did you upgrade this project from an earlier version of PG?  The release notes say, "REMOVED: Notification activityStart, activityStop, loadingStart, loadingStop core plugin functions removed in 1.0 and put in the plugins repo".  Not sure if that might have something to do with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mmigdol stated, these have been deprecated in 1.0.0

Look for them here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins