# Phonegap - Showing an ActivityIndicator while something is loading

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I take two values (source, destination) from the user and while loading the map from A to B, I need to show some sort of activity happening. We have activity indicator for iOS to do that. But how do I use the activity indicator in Phonegap while the map is loading in the background?

I'm thinking something like

```
navigator.something.activityIndicatorStartRunning()
javascript method to load the map
navigator.something.activityIndicatorStopRunning()
```

Is this possible in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

purplecabbage has a plugin for activity indicator [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the plugin link, although I can write my own plugin.. Just wanted to know if there is any javascript function to do this :-), without the need to include a plugin

Comment: They have delete the repo

Comment: As @RezaRahmati says, the repo doesn't exists anymore

Answer (score 0):

An up to date plugin providing this feature would be this

[network-activity by steve228uk](https://github.com/steve228uk/network-activity)

This can be added to cordova by

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/steve228uk/network-activity.git
```

or to PhoneGap by

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/steve228uk/network-activity.git
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This function is show custom loading indicator while load a page/JSON in phonegap

function loading() {
    $("body").addClass('ui-disabled');
    $.mobile.loading(
        'show',
        {
            text : "uploading",
            textVisible : true,
            textonly : false,
            html : "<span class='ui-bar ui-shadow ui-overlay-d ui-corner-all' style='background-color:transparent;'><div align='center'><img src='img/loader.gif' /><br/><h2 style='color:#000000; font-size:16px;text-transform:none;'>Loading...</h2></div></span>"
        });
}
```

Comment: OP clearly asked for a way to trigger the native iOS activity indicator.

Answer (score -1):

This question is quite old, but [I found this post](http://nachbaur.com/blog/telling-your-user-that-a-phonegap-application-is-busy) telling that there is a javascript function for that:

```
navigator.notification.activityStart();
// Do something that might take a while...
navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

Enjoy

Comment: This was deprecated since phonegap 1.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063910/phonegap-navigator-notification-activitystart-and-loadingstart-not-workin