# Phonegap-Navigator.notification.activityStart not working even after installing plugin

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I am using phonegap 3.5.1. I am having issue with Navigator.notification.activityStart().

When i was using phonegap 2.9.0, notification functions was working fine but it is not working on 3.5.1. I have installed the plugin "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" but still after running the app I am getting exception error like :

```
Uncaught typeError : cannot call method activityStart of undefined
```

By giving "Navigator.notification.activityStart('Please Wait','loading')" I am getting above error.

After installing plugin my config.xml updated with :

```
<feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
```

and my project's assets folder now have "plugin" folder. 
In spite of this notification alerts are not working, is there anything that i am missing?

Comment: from cli in your root folder of project run `cordova plugin ls` and check if `org.apache.cordova.dialogs` plugin is installed properly or not.

Comment: Yes it is installed properly..

Comment: i just checked the [repo](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.dialogs) of `org.apache.cordova.dialogs` but i was not able to find any method `navigator.notification.activityStart` (maybe it has been depreciated).

Comment: also check if the your method is called after `deviceReady` function is called.

Comment: Ya .. method is called after deviceReady.. is there any alternative for "loading activity" in phonegap?

Answer (score 2):

With the quick search I found following plugins:

- [cordova-activityindicator](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-activityindicator): Android and iOS supported
- [cordova-networkactivity](https://github.com/rikschennink/cordova-networkactivity): iOS only

*Also, I found a question related to `activityStart` method mentioned by you in your question.*

> Q : [Phonegap: navigator.notification.activityStart() and loadingStart() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063910/phonegap-navigator-notification-activitystart-and-%3Eloadingstart-not-workin)
>
> A :  these have been deprecated in 1.0.0